# Does Spring boot support Managed Executor Services?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, executorservice

I am new to multithreading and concurrency part, I want to know if Spring boot does support ManagedExecutorService from Java Enterprise edition concurrency which has been initiated in Java7? if yes then how? please please give information to me.

with reference to reply for comment from @akortex91:
I want to use ManagedExecutorService in my RESTful service which is a part of My SpringBoot project with default tomcat server, to write data from db to some file after certain processing using multiple threads parallel. Bcos I read that for leveraging the benefits of EE container resources ManagedExecutorService is best concurrency api provided by java and I am willing to use it in my code to understand it's usage.

One more question I do have, I read that ManagedExecutorService interface has been added since java 7. But Can I use it with Java8? if yes then how to use it using spring boot, with jdk 1.8, embedded tomcat webserver.

Comment: The correct question is what are you trying to achieve that requires this? Please include this in your question in order for someone to be able to answer it correctly.

Comment: @akortex91 i have addressed your comment . I hope it gives you all required details about my question.